# Curl - Invalid XML format for MyAnimeList Api

Tags: php, xml, curl

So I wanted to use curl to update the episodes on my list of a specific series using the [MyAnimeList Api](https://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api#updateanime). When I want to post XML data, it gives me a `Invalid XML format` response. I've seen some posts saying you should encode the data first, but that didn't resolve it (using online tools like [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html) or [this one](https://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=url&action=encode&charset=utf_8)).

```
curl -u "<dummyuser>:<dummypass>" -d data="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry><episode>18</episode><status>1</status><score>7</score><storage_type></storage_type><storage_value></storage_value><times_rewatched></times_rewatched><rewatch_value></rewatch_value><date_start></date_start><date_finish></date_finish><priority></priority><enable_discussion></enable_discussion><enable_rewatching></enable_rewatching><comments></comments><tags></tags></entry>" -k https://myanimelist.net/api/animelist/update/7791.xml
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i sure hope things are better now, but iirc, a couple of years back, their api was apparently written by a group of retarded drunk monkeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `GET` not `POST`
2. URL Encode the data

   ```
   curl -u "username:password" -d data="%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Centry%3E%3Cepisode%3E18%3C%2Fepisode%3E%3Cstatus%3E1%3C%2Fstatus%3E%3Cscore%3E7%3C%2Fscore%3E%3Cstorage_type%3E%3C%2Fstorage_type%3E%3Cstorage_value%3E%3C%2Fstorage_value%3E%3Ctimes_rewatched%3E%3C%2Ftimes_rewatched%3E%3Crewatch_value%3E%3C%2Frewatch_value%3E%3Cdate_start%3E%3C%2Fdate_start%3E%3Cdate_finish%3E%3C%2Fdate_finish%3E%3Cpriority%3E%3C%2Fpriority%3E%3Cenable_discussion%3E%3C%2Fenable_discussion%3E%3Cenable_rewatching%3E%3C%2Fenable_rewatching%3E%3Ccomments%3E%3C%2Fcomments%3E%3Ctags%3E%3C%2Ftags%3E%3C%2Fentry%3E" -k https://myanimelist.net/api/animelist/update/7791.xml -g
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your curl statement, you have the same quotes round the tag values as your using to mark the XML string (e.g. `version="1.0"`). So use single quotes round the whole -d value...

```
curl -u "<dummyuser>:<dummypass>" -d data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry><episode>18</episode><status>1</status><score>7</score><storage_type></storage_type><storage_value></storage_value><times_rewatched></times_rewatched><rewatch_value></rewatch_value><date_start></date_start><date_finish></date_finish><priority></priority><enable_discussion></enable_discussion><enable_rewatching></enable_rewatching><comments></comments><tags></tags></entry>' -k https://myanimelist.net/api/animelist/update/7791.xml
```

Comment: Already tried single quoting. Gave error: `< was unexpected at this time`.